A Question about whether the Category of Differential Equation Exists or not
I am studying undergraduate level category theory, and I am reading $\textbf{Aluffi}$'s $\textit{Algebra: Chapter 0}$ as a reference. Here is the definition of a $\textit{category}$ on $\textbf{Page 19}$ of Allufi's book:

$\textbf{Question:}$ My instructor gave me many example of category, such as Set, Ring, Field, Group, Morphism. But my question is, whether other concepts in mathematics, for example Differential Equation, can be viewed as a category which satisfies the definition here. If so, then how to define the morphism between two DEs, and what is the algebraic/geometric/any potential meaning behind it? Hope someone can help me figure it out. Thanks!

There is a notion of diffieties analogous to varieties. Maybe that can be turned into a category like varieties can be in some sense.

Thanks! I will check it.
